# Lambda Function working, but cannot work with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have a working Lambda function when I test it using a test event:

```
{
  "num1_in": 51.5,
  "num2_in": -0.097
}


import json
import Function_and_Data_List

#Parse out query string parameters
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    num1_in = event['num1_in']
    num2_in = event['num2_in']
    coord = {'num1': num1_in, 'num2': num2_in}
    output = func1(Function_and_Data_List.listdata, coord)
    return {
        "Output": output
    }
```

However, when I use API gateway to create a REST API I keep getting errors. My method for the REST API are:
1.) Build REST API
2.) Actions -> Create Resource
3.) Actions -> Create Method -> GET
4.) Integration type is Lambda Function, Use Lambda Proxy Integration
5.) Deploy

What am I missing for getting this API to work?

Comment: What are the errors you get?
Do you have necessary permission for API Gateway to invoke lambda function?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana I am an Admin - the errors are {
  "message": "Internal server error"
}Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'num1_in'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 18, "lambda_handler", "num1_in = event['num1_in']"]]}
Mon Aug 24 22:16:25 UTC 2020 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'num1_in'. Lambda request id: XXXXXX
Mon Aug 24 22:16:25 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), your playload will be in the `body`. You seem also having incorrect [return format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Therefore, I would recommend trying out the following version of your code:

```
import json
import Function_and_Data_List

#Parse out query string parameters
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(event)

    body = json.loads(event['body'])

    num1_in = body['num1_in']
    num2_in = body['num2_in']

    coord = {'num1': num1_in, 'num2': num2_in}
    output = func1(Function_and_Data_List.listdata, coord)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(output)
    }
```

In the above I also added `print(event)` so that in the CloudWatch Logs you can inspect the `event` object which should help debug the issue.